# Handling soft deletes with jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I need to perform soft deletion using jhipster.

Ex:
If user click on delete button I need to mark is_active flag to false.
Writing custom code will be the only solution or is there any way to do it?

Things I have done so far :

1. I have followed Jhipster web site and created Monolithic application.
2. Then I have created new entity called 'Student' using the entity sub-generator . (filed names : id, name age, address and is_active. )
3. The Sub generator generated files contain all the basic CRUD operations and provided a CRUD front-end for student entity.
4. The front end contains buttons for create student, view, edit and delete.
5. When I Click on a delete button the studuent record will be permanatly delete from the database.
6. But my Requirement is to keep the record in the database and mark only the is_active filed in to false.
7. Basically I need to keep history data of the student without permanatly deleting them.

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: Need more details

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please find out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC  I have updated the post with what I have done so far.

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule Updated the post with more details.

Comment: @isurikz what about modifying the delete method implementation on ServiceClass to do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to edit it yourself. First of all, I recommend you to extend all classes generated by JHipster (except for Resources, you will have to create another class and use a custom mapping thus changing the service in the frontend)

1. Extend your `StudentRepository` and create a method that updates the `is_active` value (it would be better if it receives the id and the value: true or false)
2. Extend yout `StudentService` and create a new method (e.g. call it `public void disableAddress(Long id)`)
3. In that method the your newly created method in the repository layer
4. Edit `StudentResource` and change the code inside the `deleteStudent` method and call your newly created method in the service layer
5. If you created a new resource, change the service calling your api.